# Question related to "the tree of apples" in the Bible

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, reference-request

Is it true that we tend to associate the tree whose fruit Eve convinced Adam to taste with an apple tree because of a certain translation mistake related to the word *malum*? Don't know how common this glitch is in the Latin to English translations of the Bible, but I believe it was there once in the translations from Latin into certain Romance languages.

Do you  know of a document wherein I can find the entire story of this biblical "traduttore, traditore" case?

Thanks in advance for your learned replies.

Comment: Can we assume that with "three" you mean "tree"?

Comment: Ooops, what a blunder...

Comment: There are some answers (not perhaps particularly good ones) here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13484/did-english-language-translations-describe-adam-and-eve-as-eating-apples